# axis2 Fault: The input stream for an incoming message is null

Tags: java, apache-axis

I am new to java web service and apache axis2.Every time i run my client i get an error that the input stream for an incoming message is null. What could the the issues? I have attached my log `log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.axis2.util.Loader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The input stream for an incoming message is null.
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:92)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:67)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:354)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at org.csapi.www.wsdl.parlayx.sms.notification_manager.v2_3.service.SmsNotificationManagerServiceStub.startSmsNotification(SmsNotificationManagerServiceStub.java:619)
    at org.di.custom.Notification.startNotification(Notification.java:142)
    at org.di.custom.Notification.main(Notification.java:57)`.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/8879520/283084. If it does not help, please post the relevant part of your code.

Comment: Hi @harpun i have tried the above link but i'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the **error** by adding the **settings** below in my **options** object

```
options.setProperty(Constants.Configuration.MESSAGE_TYPE,HTTPConstants.MEDIA_TYPE_APPLICATION_ECHO_XML);
options.setProperty(Constants.Configuration.DISABLE_SOAP_ACTION,Boolean.TRUE);
```

Comment: I also have same problem but your solution not work in my case.

Comment: @RizN81 solution did not work for me as well, were you able to figure out the fix ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following statement

```
options.setProperty(Constants.Configuration.DISABLE_SOAP_ACTION,Boolean.TRUE);
```

resolved the issue in my scenario.