# operationsClient.execute(true) sends the data correctly to the IBM MQ Queue, but throws axis2 exception

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, ibm-mq, apache-axis

Im trying to send data to IBM MQ Queue through some WSDL generated client stub. In stub, on this call _operationsClient(true), it calls to overriden invoke call, in this call connection is made to Queue Manager and the data is sent to the putQueue.
But when invoke call finishes, it throws exception with stackTrace as follows:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The input stream for an incoming message is null.
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:91)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:66)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:347)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:414)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:150)
```

Couldn't fine much about this when googled.
Tried this [axis2 Fault: The input stream for an incoming message is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440582/axis2-fault-the-input-stream-for-an-incoming-message-is-null) but didn't work for me. 
I'm speculating header is set wrong as before and after execute call header fields are changed, but then how come data is being sent correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For axis2 services(from architecture) we need to set 2 transports, TransportSender and transportReceiver. If its set properly then this error wont come.

But if you are not able to set it, there is workaround. 
After receiving response, manually set the input stream in messageContext. This should solve the problem.(find code below)

```
String response = "";//your manual response string
byte[] inputBuffer = new byte[4096]; 
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(inputBuffer, inputBuffer.length);
msgContext.setProperty(MessageContext.TRANSPORT_IN, new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getBytes(), 0, response.getBytes().length));
```